# Are these linear system definitions different?

Tags: linear-systems

I often find the following two definitions of linear system during my studies. Since people often refer to linear system in a generic way I suspect these defintions are somehow connected and they refers to the same thing. However, according to my understanding it's possible to find examples that satisfy just one of them (example is written below).
Can you explain if these are truly different definitions for different things or if they are related and the example I did is wrong?

**linear system:** a system of differential equations in which the unknown functions of time and space appear multiplied by known functions of time and space (or directly by constants)

**linear system:** a system in which a change in the output is proportional to a change in the input.

Example:

$\frac {d^2} {dt^2}f(t)=kA^2$ where $f(t)$ is the unknown function while $A$ is the input (a known function)

It looks like this is a linear system of differential equations (with just one equation) according to the first definition while it's a non linear system according to the second.

Answer (score 0):

If a system is a [linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system) then its output is a [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) of its input(s). For example

$f(x,y) = 3x+2y\\f(x,y) = (x+y, 2x+y)$

are linear systems, whereas

$f(x,y) = xy\\f(x,y) = (x^2, y^2)$

are not.

The differential operators $\frac {d}{dt}$, $\frac {d^2}{dt^2}$ etc. are linear, but the differential equation

$\frac {d^2f}{dt^2} = kA(t)^2$

is not linear.